# Python editing from CSV file

Tags: python, file, csv, edit

I have a CSV file which I am writing to in Python with the line:

```
writeLine = username + "," + password + "," + dob + "," + artist + "," + genre + "," + song + "\n"
```

Which outputs the following in its own column A - F:

```
Tom     Tom123    19081991    Queen   Rock    Dont Stop
```

My question is, how do I read just a particular column and edit that word? (Say I want to edit just the word 'Queen' to something else)
I can overwrite the whole line, but placing only into that column i'm a tad stuck on.

Full code is here if you wish to have a gander for full context if I have not made myself clear:

pastebin com / 6hDDBDx7 (.s removed)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6hDDBDx7    for full url

Comment: you'd be better off with the `csv` module.

Comment: If you used the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), each row would be a list and you could edit items by list index.

Comment: In addition, the `csv` modules quotes correctly the cells strings according to the CSV separator you are using. Your code does not.

Comment: You could use the `pandas` library

Answer (score 0):

You can do smth like this:

```
splitted_line = line.split(',')
splitted_line[number_of_artist_column] = new_artist
new_line = ','.join(splitted_line)
```

I think, it will be not bad in terms of code beauty